# When to delete pointer in try-catch block

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, try-catch

Quick best-practice question (note I am not allowed to use any smart pointers in this code). I am under the impression that if I pass a pointer to a function and an exceptional case occurs, then the memory is leaked if it's never deleted in either the called function or the function in which the memory was first allocated. Is it safe to delete the memory in the catch blocks or should I delete the memory in the calling function?

Example:

```
int main() {
  object* myPtr = new object(); //dynamic memory on heap
  foo(*myPtr);  //pass pointer to function foo

  return 0;
}

void foo(object &pointer) {
  try {
    /* do stuff here
    with the pointer */
  }
  catch (const char &e) {
    cout<< "An error occured: " << e << endl;
  }
  catch (...)
    cout<< "Caught unknown exception." << endl;
  }
}
```

Should I delete the pointer after the function returns?

```
 int main() {
      object* myPtr = new object(); //dynamic memory on heap
      foo(*myPtr);  //pass pointer to function foo
      delete myPtr;

      return 0;
    }
```

Or in the try-catch blocks?

```
void foo(object &pointer) {
      try {
        /* do stuff here
        with the pointer */
      }
      catch (const char &e) {
        cout<< "An error occured: " << e << endl;
        delete &pointer;
      }
      catch (...)
        cout<< "Caught unknown exception." << endl;
        delete &pointer;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use smart pointers and let the implementation and scoping handle it for you.

Comment: `void foo(object &pointer)` there's no _pointer_ at all.

Comment: just like @user0042 said. There are no pointers involved in your code. As far as I know it should not even compile, since `object myPtr` creates an instance of `object`, not a pointer to it, but `new` returns the pointer. Also, your function takes a `reference` to `object`, not a pointer to it

Comment: @JesperJuhl: _"fuck requirements"_ Not good advice really is it

Comment: @Lightness Change the order of your last two words, and you sound like Yoda ;-)

Comment: @user0042: Like Yoda I am not

Comment: @Fureeish Forgot to add the * and I fixed it. But this is a conceptual question not a syntactical one.

Comment: That does not mean you should provide us a code straight from your head. Take your time and proofread and compile the code you post here, please

Comment: @Fureeish That's understandable, my apologies.

Comment: A question you should be asking yourself is "who owns the memory? `main` or `foo`" After you've answered this question, you can better determine who is responsible for calling `delete`

Comment: @AndyG ... or which smart pointer to use.

Comment: `foo()` has no concept of how the `object` is allocated, so it is not safe to call `delete` inside of `foo()` at all.  For instance, you could call `foo()` like this instead:  `object myObj; foo(myObj);`.  Since `main()` decides how the `object` is allocated, `main()` should be the one to decide how to free it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's an answer

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - where's your inner rebel?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Inside 

Answer (score 6):

> When to delete pointer in try-catch block

Don't.

Delete it in `main`, after the call to `foo`.

In short, delete it where you created it. Anything else creates a messy asymmetry.

---

> I am under the impression that if I pass a pointer to a function and an exceptional case occurs, then the memory is leaked if it's never deleted.

Don't know where you heard that. Forget it. It's nonsense.

---

> Is it safe to delete the memory in the catch blocks or should I delete the memory in the calling function?

You could:

1. delete the memory at the end of the `try` and in both `catch` blocks
2. delete the memory after the end `try`/`catch` chain

and both are perfectly "safe".

But, like I said—

---

> Should I delete the pointer after the function returns?

Right, exactly.

---

#### BTW

You have a missing `*` and a capitalisation typo:

```
object* myPtr = new object();
//    ^             ^
```

and in reality a version with smart pointers might look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct object {};

void foo(object& obj)
{
   try {
      // do stuff here with the reference (not a pointer)
   }
   catch (const char* e) {
      std::cout << "An error occured: " << e << std::endl;
   }
   catch (...)
      std::cout << "Caught unknown exception." << std::endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   auto myPtr = std::make_unique<object>();
   foo(*myPtr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Why wouldn't the memory be leaked though if it's never deleted?

Comment: _@Lightness_ One small nitpick: The `delete` statement after the function call would be ignored after the function call in `main()` if an exception is thrown. It would matter though, if the exception is caught in `main()` and then `delete` should simply done outside of the whole `try` / `catch` construct.

Comment: @mille271 If you are referring to their last example, it is being deleted in the destructor of the smart pointer at the end of scope. That's the beauty of smart pointers, it handles it for you, correctly. edit: If you're referring to the "it's nonsense" comment they are saying that it is won't be leaked as long as it is deleted somewhere. In this case after the error is caught in the calling function. It doesn't have to be deleted where the exception occurs (in this case as the allocation wasn't done in that function, you probably wouldn't want to delete it there anyway as noted).

Comment: @mille271: You still have to delete it, but your statement suggested that merely having an exceptional case guarantees a leak. It doesn't (unless you wrote your code that way). It seems to me that someone has made a very over-simplified statement while teaching you, or your misconstrued it

Comment: @user0042: No, because `foo` catches all exceptions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: not **all** exceptions.  It is only guaranteed to catch all synchronous C++ exceptions (anything thrown using `throw`), but not asynchronous OS exceptions (access violations, page errors, stack errors, etc). `catch (...)` does not *guarantee* that those are caught.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: (a) We are discussing C++. (b) Okay, let's say you get one of those: all bets are off anyway and it makes no difference where you put your `delete` statement; it's not going to be executed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If you use a smart pointer, there is a good chance it will still be destructed, as in practice many RTLs still unwind the stack in case an OS exception is not caught, as there is usually a default OS exception handler higher up on the call stack to catch them if the code does not catch them manually (via `__try/__except`, `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()`, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Really? In my experience you get immediate program termination with nothing unwound or cleaned up at all. Maybe my runtime lib sucks :)

Comment: @Light Well, I had something different in mind (without catching exceptions inside `foo()`). You are correct.

Answer (score 3):

> I am under the impression that if I pass a pointer to a function and an exceptional case occurs, then the memory is leaked if it's never deleted in either the called function or the function in which the memory was first allocated.

It is not required that the memory be freed in the same function that allocated it.  But yes, *in general*, if the pointer is pointing at memory that was allocated with `new` then it is leaked if `delete` is never called on it at all, regardless of where that is actually called.

> Is it safe to delete the memory in the catch blocks or should I delete the memory in the calling function?

In your example, `foo()` has no concept of how the `object` is allocated, so no, it is not safe to call `delete` inside of `foo()`.

For example, you could call `foo()` using one of this instead, all of which would have problems if `foo()` called `delete`:

```
int main() {
    object myObj;
    foo(myObj);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<object> myPtr(new object);
    foo(*myPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main() {
    std::vector<char> buffer(sizeof(object));
    object *myPtr = new (&buffer[0]) object;
    foo(*myPtr);
    myPtr->~object();
    return 0;
}
```

From `foo`'s perspective, it doesn't matter  how the `object` is allocated, as long as it is a valid `object` instance going into `foo()`.  Since `main()` decides how the `object` is allocated, `main()` should be the one to decide how to free it correctly, if at all.

Comment: Watch out for alignment issues ;)